# Passing Data between User controls in C# Form application

Tags: c#, forms, user-controls

I have two user controls. I don't want to click and drag them to Form because of some reason. So I load them during the Form Load to a panel (mainPanel) in the Form and bring the required ones to front through button clicks. I will enter some data on a text box in ucFirst. What I want to do is pass this value to ucSecond's textbox through a button press in ucFirst. I am trying Event. But How could I access ucSecond's textbox  in ucFirst and reload the ucSecond with the text from user ucFirst

```
//Form.cs

public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private static Form1 _obj;
        public static Form1 Instance
        {
            get
            {
                if (_obj == null)
                    _obj = new Form1();
                return _obj;
            }
        }

        private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            _obj = this;

            //create first user control instance 
            UC_1 ucFirst = new UC_1();
            ucFirst.Dock = DockStyle.Fill;
            Form1.Instance.mainPanel.Controls.Add(ucFirst);
            //create second user control instance 
            UC_2 ucSecond = new UC_2();
            ucSecond.Dock = DockStyle.Fill;
            Form1.Instance.mainPanel.Controls.Add(ucSecond);

            //Subscribe to events
            ucFirst.TextEntered += TextAvailableFromUcFirst;


        }

        private void TextAvailableFromUcFirst(object sender, string availableText)
        {
            UC_1 ucFirst = sender as UC_1;

            //How do I use the text in ucSecond ????

            //ucSecond.textBoxUcSecond.Text = availableText;
        }

        private void showFirstUcBtn_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            Form1.Instance.mainPanel.Controls["UC_1"].BringToFront();
        }
    }

//UC_1.cs

public delegate void TextEventHandler(object sender, string text);
    public partial class UC_1 : UserControl
    {

        private static UC_1 _instance;
        public static UC_1 Instance
        {
            get
            {
                if (_instance == null)
                    _instance = new UC_1();
                return _instance;
            }
        }

        public UC_1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void UC_1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            _instance = this;
        }


        //Create an event
        public event TextEventHandler TextEntered;

        protected virtual void OnTextEntered(string text)
        {
            TextEntered?.Invoke(this, text);
        }

        private void firstUcBtn_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            //raise the event on button click
            //passing the text entered on text box

            string textBoxText = textBoxUcFirst.Text;
            OnTextEntered(textBoxText);
//I need to show the text in ucSecond textbox, but how ???
            Form1.Instance.mainPanel.Controls["UC_2"].BringToFront();
        }      
    }
```